# how can i list and choose all audio files in the device?

Tags: java, android, database, file

I'm looking forward to find an activity that can list and than choose all file of a certain type... this is qhat i have:

```
File dir = new File(".");
String[] names = dir.list(new FilenameFilter(){
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        return name.endsWith(".mp3");
    }
});
```

until this moment it can only list the file of a certain extension.
how can i use this list to make a file choose? and how can i include in this list all audio file and not only .mp3? it would be great to find a library that do so...

Comment: Don't try to do this.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a file explorer than there is a Open source sample. This open source will only show you folders and files with extension you are willing to search

Below is the URL for the same:

[Android File Dialog](https://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/)

This might solve your problem.